# IPFS API calls and Connection Refused

Tags: ipfs

I have a lot of errors using the API and I am wondering if there is anyway to debug it.

When I use

```
 curl "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/object/get?arg=QmU5KhkgvweYgE3Gsr8A19uFQrq7mszx7dubcoo89cTmAV&encoding=json"
{"Links":[],"Data":"\u0008\u0002\u0012\u000etrevor oakley\n\u0018\u000e"}
```

When I try

```
 curl "http://jenbil.com:5001/api/v0/cat?arg=QmU5KhkgvweYgE3Gsr8A19uFQrq7mszx7dubcoo89cTmAV&stream-channels=true"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to jenbil.com port 5001: Connection refused


netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address            State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8180          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      13749/ipfs      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN       1287/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13749/ipfs      
tcp        0      0 104.236.58.158:8545     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11669/geth      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13749/ipfs      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1287/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      11513/node      
tcp6       0      0 :::30303                :::*                    LISTEN      11669/geth      
tcp6       0      0 :::4001                 :::*                    LISTEN      13749/ipfs
```

Has anyone any ideas about this?

Comment: How did you solve this Trevor Lee Oakley?